# How to hide a UITableView from a UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

While doing a new app a question came to my mind.

I have a UITableView with different rows.

My first question is how to incorporate a UIButton to hide and show all the rows in our UITableView but the first one. It's like a pull-down-menu where the button deploy all the rows of the Table, and whether we click again we could see the first row only. In this case it would be sunny.

And my second question is that when clicking a row in the UITableView a TextField should be changed with the name of the row that had just been clicked. How to do this?

Thanks for your help.

[image: Our app]

Comment: You can change the height of the table and change the count of the row when you select the button. and when you select any row get your text fields object and give the text to that text field

Answer (score 0):

To show and hide you can use the TableView header and can show and hide on button press. If you need third party or just help please see this [sample](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/rrncollapsablesectiontableview).

And to for the second question in you didselectRowAtIndex path method you can assign the value to text field.

Comment: Hi man!! This example doesn't work and I do not know why. Maybe for the last update of XCode and perhaps because it was in Objective C.

Comment: Yes bro. I would prefer it

Comment: here it is  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/expandabletableview . Please convert to 2.0 when Xcode asks in the start.

Comment: Another one this one better in your case https://github.com/fawazbabu/Accordion_Menu